# How does Django handle multiple CRUD actions on same table? (at same time)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am curious about how Django handles multiple actions to be performed on same table **at the same time**. I'm using Postgresql with Django ORM.

Does it have locking mechanism to handle such scenario?

If yes then is it by default or any parameter must be added?

Comment: Same table? Of course things work as you'd expect, with the transactionality guaranteed provided by your database. Same row? `select_for_update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django offers `select_for_update` manager method for database locking. Be aware that your code must be wrapped with `transaction.atomic` in order to achieve locking. Otherwise multiple database queries for the same data will not prevent each other. Look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) for more details.